# How to animate marker on google maps ?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, objectanimator

What i'm trying to achieve supposed to be very simple, yet it's not working. 
I have added a marker on my map, and i'm trying to animate it an heart beat.

I have tried the following code, but without no luck,

```
   ObjectAnimator pulse = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(userLocation,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX",2f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY",2f)
            );
    pulse.setDuration(310);
    pulse.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    pulse.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
    pulse.start();
```

any suggestion would be grateful, 
plus using an external library can be an option as well, I have just didn't find one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

General approach well described in [Cabezas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347071/6950238). In addition to his answer, for your task You should apply it for setting (resized according `Interpolator` for each frame of animation) bitmap for marker. For example, You can do it by using method like this:

```
private void pulseMarker(final Bitmap markerIcon, final Marker marker, final long onePulseDuration) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final Interpolator interpolator = new CycleInterpolator(1f);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / onePulseDuration);
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(scaleBitmap(markerIcon, 1f + 0.05f * t)));
            handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
        }
    });
}
```

where 16 is duration of one frame of animation, `1f + 0.05f * t` - is 5% increase and decrease of size of marker icon and `scaleBitmap()` is:

```
public Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float scaleFactor) {
    final int sizeX = Math.round(bitmap.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
    final int sizeY = Math.round(bitmap.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, sizeX, sizeY, false);
    return bitmapResized;
}
```

and call is:

```
Bitmap markerIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_heart);
pulseMarker(markerIcon, marker, 1000);
```

where `marker` is your marker, `1000` - 1 sec duration of one pulse.

Comment: @andrji is it possible to set duration only for 2 seconds, its working infinite time..

Comment: @JhamanDas Easiest way to do that is to "surround" lines from `float t =...` to `handler.postDelayed(this, 16);` inclusive by `if` statement:  `if (elapsed < 2000) {`. It means that if time spent since `startTime` less 2 sec (2000 in millis) we need to call next "step" of animation (`handler.postDelayed(this, 16);`). Otherwise - not.