# Use an animated Layout for a Google Map marker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, animation, bitmap

I'm trying to use an animated Layout for a Google Maps Marker. However, in Google Documentation they only speak about drawables (Bitmaps). **The difficulty is only one part of the Layout is rotating. It means, that I can't convert the Layout into a Bitmap and animate the whole Bitmap.**

I read the following topic [Using an xml Layout for a Google Map Marker for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24716987/8219923) that is really similar to my problem. Then I also read the following topic [GIF type animation for marker in google map api ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715920/gif-type-animation-for-marker-in-google-map-api-android)

According to these topics, my code should be something like that (not sure it works!) :

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
            .title("name")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myfunction())));

private final int ONE_SECONDS = 1000;
public Bitmap myfunction(){
    // how to do there ?
}
```

However, I have some problems:

- How to return a 'animated' Bitmap in the myfunction() ? I mean, how to return a different Bitmap each 100 ms ?
- Is this solution a good way ? Because returning a different Bitmap each 100 ms may use a lot of memory for only one animation (and the animation could be not very fluid)...

Actually, maybe I should forget Google Maps ?

---

**EDIT :** I tried the solutions given by andrii-omelchenko however this way isn't good. It consumes so much resources for one animated marker !

I found an application doing what I want : ZENLY. Take a look there : https://youtu.be/0S-W8oSnzr0?t=18s 
**How to do the same marker ?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347772/6950238) answer.

Comment: Your solution is almost good. Thanks to you I can update the markerIcon periodically. Now, I need to transform my animated Layout into Bitmap**s** (an array of Bitmap maybe). How to do this ? Thanks again for your time

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200559/6950238) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036736/6950238), but better IMHO use bitmap transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you gave to me, however it use too much resources just for one animated marker. I must found another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great solution : using `TileOverlay` : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay

So you have to add different forms such as circles and polygons and make their properties being dynamics.

It's consequently difficult just for obtaining this result !